# How to bind a WPF windows Width & Height but still having the WindowStarupLocation correctly used?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I've a service that displays windows for me. Basically, I receive the ViewModel, find the adequate View(based on a naming convention). Set the owner to the window and display it.

This is the part that works really fine.

In the xaml of the window that I display, I'm now adding a binding to the ViewModel for the Width and Height(in this case, this View is used to host very different wizards, so I need to be able to provide different parameters.

The window is of the correct size, BUT, it's not centered on the owner anymore. With hardcoded Width/Height, everything is well centered.

I **guess** the binding is done AFTER the window is shown(??) and then the size is changed, having the correct size, but not centered?

Is it possible to have the behavior I expect?

Some code:

My service:
        public bool? ShowCustomDialog(ICustomDialogViewModel viewModel)
        {
            bool? dialogResult = null;

```
        void ShowAction()
        {
            Type viewType = _viewService.GetViewType(viewModel.GetType());
            Window dialog = (Window)Activator.CreateInstance(viewType);
            dialog.Owner = FindOwner();
            dialog.DataContext = viewModel;
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = RegisterDialogResult(dialog, viewModel);
            dialogResult = dialog.ShowDialog();
            UnregisterDialogResult(viewModel, handler);
        }

        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeIfRequired(ShowAction);
        return dialogResult;
    }
```

And the Xaml:

```
<dx:ThemedWindow x:Class="My.View"
    <!--...-->
    Width="{Binding WindowWidth, Mode=OneTime}" 
    MinWidth="{Binding WindowWidth, Mode=OneTime}" 
    Height="{Binding WindowHeight, Mode=OneTime}" 
    MinHeight="{Binding WindowHeight, Mode=OneTime}" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" 
    WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow" 
    ResizeMode="NoResize"  
    ShowInTaskbar="False" >
    <!--...-->
</dx:ThemedWindow>
```

Comment: It's had no time to get the binding data. If you make your showaction async try putting an await task.delay(1000) before show and see if that works ok. Then think of a more sophisticated way to do it.